# toggle menu with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

One of the theme I am using on wordpress use toggle menu if the parent menu have child menu under.

This is the current js code

```
    var navItemDropdown = $('#nav li .dropdown');
navItemDropdown.each(function(){
    thisDropdown = $(this);
    $(this).parent().prepend('<span class="sub-nav-toggle"></span>');
});

$('body').on('click','.sub-nav-toggle',function(event){

    $(this).parents('li').toggleClass('active');
    thisDropdown = $(this).parents('li').find('.dropdown');
    thisDropdown.slideToggle('fast');
    return false;

});
```

It's added `<span class="sub-nav-toggle"></span>` if there's a child menu.

The code of menu which have child menu becomes like this

```
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-22"><span class="sub-nav-toggle"></span><a href="#">About Us</a>
<section class="dropdown"><ul>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-26"><a href="page_id=6">Who we are</a></li>
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-25"><a href="page_id=7">Our Vision</a></li>
</ul></section>
</li>
```

What I would like to achieve is instead of injecting the `<span class="sub-nav-toggle"></span>`, I would like to insert class="sub-nav-toggle" inside the a href tag. Which means `<a>` tag will become like this

```
<a class="sub-nav-toggle" href="#">About Us</a>
```

There's a way I can add the class for the menu through Wordpress Menu, but it's only added the class inside `<li>` tag instead of `<a>` tag, so it's not working and cannot do that way.

Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: The only thing I see even remotely possible as a question is, "... instead of injecting class sub-nav-toggle, inject with class sub-nav-goggle for a href" Which sounds like an order, so what _is_ your question exactly?

Comment: Hello, sorry if my question or explanation is confusing. What I am trying to say is instead of injecting "<span class="sub-nav-toggle"></span>" this code, I would like javascript to find "<a>" tag and inject the class code, so it would become like this "<a class="sub-nav-toggle" href="#">About Us</a>". Thanks.

Comment: And my bad, it's typo. It should be sub-nav-toggle -_-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need  to change this:

```
$(this).parent().prepend('<span class="sub-nav-toggle"></span>');
```

to this:

```
$(this).prev().addClass('sub-nav-toggle');
```